# Conditional to compare three values

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I am trying to determine if there is a way for me to write an `if` statement that will result in `true` if three values are equal to each other.

EX:

```rb
if a == b == c
   puts "true"
end
```

Instead of having to write:

```rb
if a == b && a == c && b == c
```

Comment: You only need `a == b && b == c`. It is then implied that `a == c`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need all 3, if `a` equal `b` and `c` equal `b` it implies `a` equal `c`.

If you need it more scalable 3+ arguments, you can do:

```rb
Set[a, b, c].size == 1
```

---

Original answer was:

```rb
Set[a, b, c].one?
```

But it `one?` does not count `nil` or `false` elements. So `Set[nil, nil].one?` will be `false`.

Thanks to Sagar Pandya for pointing it out in the comments.

Comment: What if you have an array of nil or false objects?

Comment: It'll work as expected. Meaning, if you wanted to check (pseudo code) `nil == nil == nil` or `false == false == false` both will be `true`.

Comment: `Set[nil, nil, nil].one? #=> false`. I don't think `one?` does what you expect it to be doing.

Comment: Ha! Good spot, `Set[nil, nil].size == 1` better then.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```rb
  [a, b, c].uniq.size == 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Bodacious mentioned `a == b && b == c` would work due to the transitive property.

But if you have many items, you could do something like:

```
values = [a, b, c]
if values.all? { |value| value == value[0] }
  puts "true"
end
```

The [`all?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) method returns true if a block returns true for every item. So in that block, check to see if every item is equal to the first item.